# XMLHttpRequest timing out

Tags: javascript, html, xml, http, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a JavaScript application that reads sensor data from a Wiznet W5500 chip hosting a web server. I am using the XMLHttpRequest object. I am monitoring the packet traffic with Wireshark. I can see that my HTTP/XML string is being sent, and Wireshark recognizes the HTTP headers and XML format. However when I try to read the data in my JavaScript application, it is NULL.

Here is my relevant JavaScript Code.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/JavaScript">

var x = "<strong>Offline</strong>";
var y = "<strong>Offline</strong>";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var periodMS = 20000;       
var timeoutMS = 1500;
console.log('READY STATE: UNSENT', xhr.readyState);
console.log('STATUS: UNSENT', xhr.status); 
var data;

setInterval(function(){
   xhr.open('GET', 'http://192.168.1.123/', true); 
   xhr.timeout = timeoutMS;

   if (xhr.readyState==1){console.log('READY STATE: OPENED', xhr.readyState);}
   if (xhr.status==0){console.log('STATUS: OPENED', xhr.status);}
   xhr.send(null);


   xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      if (xhr.readyState==0){console.log('OPEN NOT CALLED');}
      if (xhr.readyState==1){console.log('OPEN CALLED', xhr.responseText);}
      if (xhr.readyState==2){
console.log('HEADERS AND STATUS AVAILABLE', xhr.responseText);}
      if (xhr.readyState==3){console.log('LOADING');}
      if (xhr.readyState==4){
         console.log('DONE',xhr.statusText,xhr.responseXML);
         x = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("temp")[0].firstChild.data;
         console.log('TEMPERATURE=', x);
         document.getElementById("temperature").innerHTML = "<font size='+7'>" + x + "</font>";

         y = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("humid")[0].firstChild.data; 

         console.log('HUMIDITY=', y);
         document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = "<font size='+7'>" + y + "</font>";
}}

   xhr.ontimeout = function () {

console.log('STATUS: TIMEOUT', xhr.status); 
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "<font size='+7' color='#FF0000'>" + x + "</font>";

      document.getElementById("humid").innerHTML = "<font size='+7' color='#FF0000'>" + y + "</font>";};


}, periodMS)        


</SCRIPT>
```

When the XMLHttpRequest.send command executes, I can see on Wireshark a successful SYN handshake, GET/HTTP request to my server, server replies with HTTP/XML protocol, server does a TCP retransmission, then JavaScript application ACK and FIN handshake. Here is a screen capture of my Wireshark capture, showing the details of the HTTP/XML response, and it shows the console output when I run my interval function once.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9866h.png)

Here is the exact string I am sending from my server, in quotes.

```
"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 122\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WatlowSense><temperature>29.40</temperature><humidity>7.75</humidity></WatlowSense>"
```

Am I sending an incorrect response from my server for this protocol? Is something wrong with my JavaScript code? Thank you, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: font tags have been deprecated for decades...

Comment: what is the repsonseText?

Comment: `Here is the exact string I am sending from my server, in quotes` - you're sending headers only - I'd expect to see `Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n` - i.e. a blank line before the response data - the client expects 122 bytes (content length) and never gets it because of the poor response format

Comment: i.e. teh response SHOULD be `"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 140\r\nContent-Type: text/xml\r\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\nConnection: Keep-Alive\r\n\r\n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WatlowSense><temperature>29.40</temperature><humidity>7.75</humidity></WatlowSense>"` - note the content-length SHOULD be 140 if you send 140 bytes (your original response in the question has `Content-Length:122` and the (poorly done) response is 140 bytes long!!!

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks for your help, I will try out this fix tomorrow and see what comes of it. Why is the Content-Length:140? I thought it meant the length of the XML string, which is 122 chars in this example. Also can you elaborate on why the response is poorly done?

Comment: I can assure you `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WatlowSense><temperature>29.40</temperatu‌​re><humidity>7.75</h‌​umidity></WatlowSens‌​e>` is 140 characters - I counted twice before I said so :p

Comment: hmmm ... I better count again ... something ODD happening here :p

Comment: damn!!! your length is correct 122 ... but the main issue is still valid

Comment: The blank line before my data did the trick! Many thanks